# Compile different android modules using different android APIs

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have two modules: my application's module, which I want  to be compiled using **Android 2.3 platform**, and ActionBarSherlock library module, which has to be compiled with **Android 4.0 platform**. When I set project structure that way and run application (and ActionBarSherlock is set as dependency of my module) - IDEA tries to compile everything with 2.3 API, and displays errors like this:

> android-apt-compiler:
>   action-bar-sherlock\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:32: error: Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'

How to set IDEA properly?

Comment: In each module you can set required version. Question is why you want to compile ABS every time you compile your project. Why not either link Jake git repo or build library locally and add it to project?

Comment: Because to use ABS as Intellij module is the only way to include it in project. That module is set as dependency of main module. And it always recompiles.

Comment: Maven based Android project and you can included it as dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile everything with the 4.0 libs, but support 2.3 using the following manifest declarations:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

In the example, 17 is the current latest API version, but you can use 15, or whatever you need.

Comment: But Intellij allows to use API classes from 14th SDK (for example, android.util.LruCache) even if minSdkVersion is set to 10. It is misleading.

Comment: @Taras, that is not related to this question. The provided answer will resolve your build issues. With regards to it being misleading, I completely agree - Eclipse warns you when you use high-level APIs in a "compatibility" app. However, that's an editor problem that you'll have to live with I guess.

Comment: Also, it's best practice to compile with the latest version of the SDK even if you are supporting lower level APIs due to bugfixes and improvements in the SDK itself.